# Does mercurial-server support subrepo?

Tags: mercurial, subrepos, mercurial-server

I installed mercurial-server on one of my machines, cloned my project there, it has 3 subrepos, and when I try to clone it back to another location I get an error:

> remote: mercurial-server: Cannot
>   create repo under existing repo
>
> abort: no suitable response from
>   remote hg!

So I'm starting to think that mercurial-server doesn't handle subrepo.

Any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got an answer from the developers of mercurial-server saying that they don't support it yet.

Comment: The most recent versions of mercurial-server do support subrepos.

Answer (score 5):

[The new version released in December 2010](http://www.lshift.net/blog/2010/12/19/mercurial-server-version-11-released) does support sub repos.

Answer (score 1):

Their [changelog](http://hg.opensource.lshift.net/mercurial-server/file/default/NEWS) never mentions [subrepos](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/subrepos).
Nor does [their documentation](http://dev.lshift.net/paul/mercurial-server/docbook.html).

So it is quite possible they don"t support that feature yet, but I wouldn't know for sure.

Answer (score 1):

This [post](http://groups.google.com/group/mercurial_general/browse_thread/thread/295ab930c95aeea9?pli=1) says that disabling the "checkParents" code will enable support for subrepos.

**EDIT**

I've tried using it recently and it works just fine even without changing any default settings.

Answer (score 0):

I found that you need to set up the locations for any subrepos inside the "mercurial.ini" settings file.

For a subrepo named "mysubrepo", you need to add the line

```
[subpaths]
mysubrepo = ssh://hg@myserver/subrepolocation
```